# Clicking on the edge of the Answer (or similar) button won't perform the action

Tags: bug, design

Recently I noticed that clicking on the edge of the Answer button (or any button which has the same style) *will* depress the button visually, but *will not* perform the action (won't post the answer).  I need to make sure that I click on the middle and not the edge.  I took a while before I figured out why these buttons didn't seem to react sometimes.  It is quite confusing that the button-press animation works fine, the button just doesn't perform the action.

[image]

Can anyone confirm the problem?  You can edit one of your old posts and use the Save Edits button.

I am using Chrome on OS X.

**EDIT:** Please try the upper edge of the button.  With the lower edge I can't consistently reproduce the problem, but with the upper edge I can.

**EDIT 2:** I can see the problem with Safari 6.0.5 and with Chrome 30.  Firefox 24 doesn't show the problem.

Comment: FYI I have the same problem with the upper edge on Chrome 29 W7.

Comment: Reproduced at upper edge under Firefox 23.0.1, Windows 7, 64-bit, though behaviour is not consistent: sometimes it does perform the action, sometimes does not.